# How do I make my Kubernetes replication controller use a certain secret to pull an image?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry

I have specified a certain [image pull secret](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/images.html#specifying-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod) for my replication controller, but it doesn't appear to be applied when downloading the Docker image:

```
$ ~/.local/bin/kubectl --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kube.conf get events
FIRSTSEEN   LASTSEEN   COUNT     NAME                                             KIND      SUBOBJECT              REASON           SOURCE                                                        MESSAGE
8h          8s         3074      web-73na4                                        Pod       spec.containers{web}   Pulling          {kubelet ip-172-31-29-110.eu-central-1.compute.internal}      Pulling image "quay.io/aknuds1/realtime-music"
8h          5s         3074      web-73na4                                        Pod       spec.containers{web}   Failed           {kubelet ip-172-31-29-110.eu-central-1.compute.internal}      Failed to pull image "quay.io/aknuds1/realtime-music": image pull failed for quay.io/aknuds1/realtime-music, this may be because there are no credentials on this request.  details: (Error: Status 403 trying to pull repository aknuds1/realtime-music: "{\"error\": \"Permission Denied\"}")
```

How do I make the replication controller use the image pull secret "quay.io" when downloading the image? The replication controller spec looks as follows:

```
{
  "kind": "ReplicationController",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "web",
    "labels": {
      "app": "web"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "replicas": 1,
    "selector": {
      "app": "web"
    },
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "labels": {
          "app": "web"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "web",
            "image": "quay.io/aknuds1/realtime-music",
            "ports": [
              {
                "name": "http-server",
                "containerPort": 80
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "imagePullSecrets": [
          {
            "name": "quay.io"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## Edit

I created the quay.io secret like this: `~/.local/bin/kubectl --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kube.conf create -f /tmp/image-pull-secret.yaml`. The content of /tmp/image-pull-secret.yaml is basically like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: quay.io
data:
  .dockercfg: <base64 encoded dockercfg>
type: kubernetes.io/dockercfg
```

## Output from `kubectl get pods web-73na4 -o yaml`, in response to @PaulMorie

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/created-by: |
      {"kind":"SerializedReference","apiVersion":"v1","reference":{"kind":"ReplicationController","namespace":"default","name":"web","uid":"e1b7a3f0-e349-11e5-a136-02420a022e02","apiVersion":"v1","resourceVersion":"31503"}}
  creationTimestamp: 2016-03-06T03:16:56Z
  generateName: web-
  labels:
    app: web
  name: web-73na4
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "31516"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/web-73na4
  uid: e1b89066-e349-11e5-a136-02420a022e02
spec:
  containers:
  - image: quay.io/aknuds1/realtime-music
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: web
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
      name: http-server
      protocol: TCP
    resources: {}
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: default-token-5s7kd
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  nodeName: ip-172-31-29-110.eu-central-1.compute.internal
  restartPolicy: Always
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  volumes:
  - name: default-token-5s7kd
    secret:
      secretName: default-token-5s7kd
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: null
    status: "False"
    type: Ready
  containerStatuses:
  - image: quay.io/aknuds1/realtime-music
    imageID: ""
    lastState: {}
    name: web
    ready: false
    restartCount: 0
    state:
      waiting:
        message: 'image pull failed for quay.io/aknuds1/realtime-music, this may be
          because there are no credentials on this request.  details: (Error: Status
          403 trying to pull repository aknuds1/realtime-music: "{\"error\": \"Permission
          Denied\"}")'
        reason: PullImageError
  hostIP: 172.31.29.110
  phase: Pending
  podIP: 10.2.2.3
  startTime: 2016-03-06T03:16:56Z
```

Comment: I think @JesusRT's answer might be correct -- let's establish that you have a secret named 'quay.io' in the namespace of your replication controller.  What's the output of `kubectl get secrets` in this namespace?

Comment: @PaulMorie ```$ ~/.local/bin/kubectl --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kube.conf get secrets
NAME                  TYPE                                  DATA      AGE
default-token-5s7kd   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   2         1d
quay.io               kubernetes.io/dockercfg               1         6h```

Comment: Interesting @aknuds1, can I see the log from the kubelet for the node the pod from the replication controller was assigned to?  That will help us debug what happened with the pull secret.

Comment: @PaulMorie If I try to get the logs of pod `web-73na4` (I think this is the pod you want, see my question for reference on how I found it), nothing is shown. What should I do?

Comment: what I want is the kubelet log.  The kubelet is the piece of the system that is responsible for starting and stopping containers on each node.  It's also the component that actually uses the image pull secret on your behalf to pull the image.  Let's start by figuring out which node the pod was assigned to -- can you post the output of `kubectl get pods <pod name> -o yaml` ?

Comment: @PaulMorie Sorry, misunderstanding on my part. I added the output you requested to the question.

Comment: I guess this question should really be about how to debug Kubernetes' application of Docker registry credentials...

Comment: @PaulMorie After deleting the replication controller and then recreating it, the credentials were actually applied! Before, I used `kubectl replace`, I guess maybe it didn't work quite as I expected? At least I can see `imagePullSecrets` in the `get pod` output, so thanks for that technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** (That is what I did to use a private image):

First log in quay.io:

```
$ docker login quay.io
Username (username):
Password:
WARNING: login credentials saved in /Users/user/.docker/config.json
Login Succeeded
```

Then I created a new file (my-credentials.json) that only had the quay.io credentials that docker added in the config.json file (I realized that it had more credentials apart from the quay.io).

```
$ cat config.json
{
  "quay.io": {
    "auth": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "email": "user@example.com"
  }
}
```

After that, I generated the base64:

```
 $ cat ./my-credentials.json | base64
 <base64-value>
```

And I created the secret resource:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: myregistrykey
data:
  .dockercfg: <base64-value>
type: kubernetes.io/dockercfg

$ kubectl create -f image-pull-secret.yaml
```

Finally, I created the pod:

```
{
  "kind": "ReplicationController",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "web",
    "labels": {
      "app": "web"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "replicas": 1,
    "selector": {
      "app": "web"
    },
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "labels": {
          "app": "web"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "web",
            "image": "quay.io/username/myimage",
            "ports": [
              {
                "name": "http-server",
                "containerPort": 80
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "imagePullSecrets": [
          {
            "name": "myregistrykey"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

$ kubectl create -f pod.yaml
```

I have used `myregistrykey` as the name of the `imagePullSecrets` instead of `quay.io`, but I don't think that the issue is for that.

---

The issue seems to be due to you didn't create a `secret` to save your credentials.

Note that the value of the `name` key in the `imagePullSecrets` section (in your case "quay.io") should be the same that you specified in your `secret` resource.

Comment: I thought it went without saying, but I have of course created the secret before.

Comment: I have just followed the steps provide by the kubernetes guide and I have been able to pull an image that is in a private repository in quay.io. Could you check that the credentials that your are passing are corrects?

Comment: Do you have a link to the guide in question?

Comment: The one that you pasted: http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/images.html#specifying-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod

Comment: Well, the difference is the guide uses a pod definition whereas I use a replication controller definition. Either way, it doesn't work, so it doesn't help me much :/

Comment: I have updated the reply. Maybe the issue could be that the credentials are not set properly.

Comment: I cannot see what I've done differently from you. I really wish I could see some logs about how Kubernetes is picking up or ignoring my `imagePullSecrets`.

Comment: I  have realized that in the log that you pasted, there  isn't any `imagePullSecrets` field, could you check if updating the gcloud sdk as well as the kubectl the issue solves?

Comment: gcloud sdk? I'm on AWS.

Comment: Seems as if this procedure really does work. What probably didn't work was updating the replication controller spec, as it started working only after I deleted the replication controller before re-creating it rather than relying on `kubectl replace`. Not entirely sure what made the difference yet, but hey, it's working.